Examples of temperature-dependent quantum channels
I am looking for examples of instances or families of quantum channels that arise out of an interaction of a quantum system with an environment having some temperature. For instance, the generalized amplitude damping channel (of Nielsen and Chuang, Sec. 8.3.5) can be modelled as a unitary interaction
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&\sqrt{1-\gamma}&\sqrt{\gamma}&0\\
0&-\sqrt{\gamma}&\sqrt{1-\gamma}&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
between a system and an environment in a thermal state $(1-e^{-\beta})|0\rangle\langle 0| + e^{-\beta}(1-e^{-\beta})|1\rangle\langle 1|$, followed by discarding the environment.
I am especially interested in channels that experimentalists would use to model plausible temperature-dependent interactions in existing implementations of qubits.

Does this answer your question?

That's a great example of such channels!
